# Filtering data in firebase in ionic

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm still quite new to firebase, and I need guidance on how to filter firebase's data in ionic. Currently, I am trying to get users where if user key's 'Apply' is true, data is called. So far, there were answers on the web which said to use orderByChild statement (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) but I'm not sure whether that can be applied in this situation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use firebase database `orderByChild` and `equalTo` methods.

OrderByChild from firebase reference:

> orderByChild
>   orderByChild(path) returns firebase.database.Query
>
> It generates a new Query object ordered by the specified child key.
>
> Queries can only order by one key at a time. Calling orderByChild() multiple times on the same query is an error.

equalTo from firebase reference:

> equalTo(value, key) returns firebase.database.Query
>
> Creates a Query that includes children that match the specified value.
>
> Using startAt(), endAt(), and equalTo() allows us to choose arbitrary starting and ending points for our queries.
>
> The optional key argument can be used to further limit the range of the query. If it is specified, then children that have exactly the specified value must also have exactly the specified key as their key name. This can be used to filter result sets with many matches for the same value.
>
> Firebase queries allow you to order your data by any child key on the fly. However, if you know in advance what your indexes will be, you can define them via the .indexOn rule in your Security Rules for better performance.

Code for your issue:

```
const requestRef = firebase.database().ref('request');
requestRef.orderByChild('apply')
          .equalTo(true)
          .once('value')
          .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
          .then((data) => {// your handle code here})
```

Full documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equalTo)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use OrderByChild in your case as well. This should work.

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('request').orderByChild('apply').equalTo('true');
query.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val()) //contains all users that has apply as true
})
```

Comment: This indeed works, although I'd recommend looping over the results instead of logging them (to ensure they maintain their order). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events Also: strictly speaking that is no longer a `ref`, but a query. :-)